# Generate a worksheet button with preassigned code

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to do more or less as the author has intended here:

http://ccm.net/faq/1105-adding-a-vba-commandbutton-with-its-respective-the-code

unfortunately, although the code is written to the correct sheet in Microsoft Excel Objects, the code does not run once the button is pressed.  The `_Click()` is here:

```
Sub ButtonTest_Click()
MsgBox "I am supposed to work!" 'but i dont, i actually do nothing
End Sub
```

and the rest of the code is below:

```
Sub CreateButton()            

Dim Obj As Object            
Dim Code As String            

Sheets("Sheet1").Select            

'create button            
Set Obj = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.CommandButton.1", _            
Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=200, Top:=100, Width:=100, Height:=35)            
Obj.Name = "TestButton"            
'buttonn text            
ActiveSheet.OLEObjects(1).Object.Caption = "Test Button"            

'macro text            
Code = "Sub ButtonTest_Click()" & vbCrLf            
Code = Code & "Msgbox ""I am supposed to work!""" & vbCrLf            
Code = Code & "End Sub"            
'add macro at the end of the sheet module            
With ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(ActiveSheet.Name).CodeModule            
    .insertlines .CountOfLines + 1, Code            
end With            
End Sub
```

nothing happens when the button is pressed- to my mind it looks like it should fire the event as author intended, any ideas why it doesn't?

Comment: `TestButton` and `ButtonTest_Click` don't match. Rename either the button or the procedure, then try it again.

Comment: Change `Obj.Name = "TestButton"` to `Obj.Name = "ButtonTest"`. The name of the button and the name of the sub have to coincode for ActiveX components.

Comment: Can't believe i missed it, add an answer mike and the big green tick is yours.

Comment: Glad it worked. RE:Karma, I'm in it to help, not to earn useless internet points. @Ralph also answered near-simultaneously with the same correct explanation. The internet point are all his, if he wants.

Comment: @Mikegrann with more points you can help this site more. For example: with 3,000 points or more you can start helping us clean up this site and [cast close or reopen votes](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions). With four close votes a post / answer gets removed and we don't have to stroll through all these incomplete posts anymore when searching for applicable / usable Q&As. Of course, this is just one example. So, maybe you wanna start adding to your "Karma" and help us some more improve this site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating ActiveX components. Unlike form components you cannot name the underlying macros as you wish. The macros' names **must** start with the name of the ActiveX component followed by and underscore and the even name.

So, if your ActiveX component is named TestButton (according to this):

```
Obj.Name = "TestButton"
```

Then the sub's name to handle the `click` event must be named:

```
Sub TestButton_Click()
```

Hence, you'll have to rename the sub or you must change the name for the ActiveX component to match.

Alternatively, you can also implement form controls. The following three lines of code create a new form control `CheckBox` and assigns your macro to it (when clicked):

```
Dim chk As CheckBox
Set chk = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Add(390.75, 216, 72, 72)
chk.OnAction = "ButtonTest_Click"
```